# Quartz Job Scheduling to call DB: Pass DB reference or re-connect for every Job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I need a Quartz job to retrieve data from a Database.

From reading the documents it recommends using simple primitive types in the Quartz Job Execution

My Question is this - should I:

1. Re-initialize my connection to the DB every time the Quartz Job Fires
2. Pass the DB connection object as a parameter to the Quartz Object

Comment: did you referred their documentation ?

Comment: Yep. I mention that in the question

Comment: Wonder how you are going to pass connection to Quartz job. Anyways, in all of cron jobs I have written in past I just use connection pool (from Spring for example) and create/close the connection on each job run.

Comment: Why don't you just call your Services from the job, where connection to database already exists? Are you going to use a different datasource?

Comment: @Izagkaretos from reading the Quartz documentation, that approach is not recommended